# How to parse hidden characters to parse string to date from CSV

Tags: java, macos, date

I'm working with dates in java with `eclipse` and `yosemite`, then when I'm trying to parse a simple string to Date,but not works, this is my simple example

```java
String fecha = "2015-06-14";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    df.parse(fecha).getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the following problem:

```java
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-06-14"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

I tasted this code on `linux` and is works, I don't know what am I doing wrong?

I'm using java 1.7 because is requeried for a project

```
java version "1.7.0_80-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-ea-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b07, mixed mode)
```

This is my timezone

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Bogota",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=5,lastRule=null]
Tue May 19 12:22:39 COT 2015
```

I use the following to check hidden characters:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fecha.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)))

 [0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, 53, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, 53, 0, 0]
```

How to parse the right way the CSV

I use the following to read the `csv file`

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = "\t";
        try {
            int counter = 0 ; 
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if( line.length() > 1 ){

                    String[] urvLine = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                    String fecha = String.valueOf( urvLine[0] );
                    String value = String.valueOf( urvLine[1] );
                    log.debug( Arrays.toString(fecha.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)) );
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Maybe there are hidden characters somewhere in your `fecha` or the date format? Can you delete those two lines  from your program and re-type them? Your program works for me in all locales on Yosemite, though my Java is 1.7.0_71.

Comment: probably you have reazon, because I import a string from csv, so  is there some way check and delete this hidden characters?

Comment: First, have you tried just printing them? If they look OK when printed, try using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fecha.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)))` and put the result as an edit in your question.

Comment: @CristianChaparroA. As RealSkeptic says, there must be some other problem. **Your code for parsing the string looks correct.** Do verify your input string value(s). Check the length of the string programmatically to see if it is indeed ten characters ( 4 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 ). On your Mac, download the very handy [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) app to examine the individual octets of your input file. Use a text editor (TextEdit, TextMate, etc.) to create your own input text file by typing text yourself.

Comment: Please post your exact input file.

Comment: Given that your exception cites line `357`, you must have a lot of other code going on. I suggest creating an alternate app with absolutely minimal code necessary to show the problem.